# Checking if a username is valid

Tags: c++

I'm learning about how to create a good and clean code. I just need to review something like that, and I really not sure how can I fix this code into a clean code.

```
bool isValidUserName(const std::string& username)
{
    bool valid = false;

    if (username.length() >= MIN_NAME_LENGTH)
    {
        if (username.length() <= MAX_NAME_LENGTH)
        {
            if (isalpha(username[0]))
            {
                bool foundNotValidChar = std::find_if(username.begin(), username.end(), isNotValid) != username.end();
                if (!foundNotValidChar)
                {
                    valid = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return valid;
}
```

thank you very much!, i replied lately because i had to do something and i forgot about it already

Comment: Is this your own code? Also, what do you mean by "arrow code"? I don't see any arrows.

Comment: I think @TiZ_Crocodile means that if-statements in the code are nested like "christmas tree" which also looks like "arrow"

Comment: @G.Sliepen "arrow anti-pattern" is a common name for code where the `{}` start to look like an arrow head (a triangle). For example, Jeff Atwood [blogged about the arrow anti-pattern a while ago](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We can avoid the excessive indentation by returning early.

Instead of checking for validity:

```
if (username.length() >= MIN_NAME_LENGTH)
{
    ... additional nested checks...
}
```

we reverse the check and return as soon as possible:

```
if (username.length < MIN_NAME_LENGTH)
    return false; // done!
```

So overall we'd get something like:

```
if (username.length() < MIN_NAME_LENGTH || username.length() > MAX_NAME_LENGTH)
    return false;

if (username.empty() || !std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(username.front()))) // paranoia: avoid crashing with empty username
    return false;

if (std::find_if(username.begin(), username.end(), isNotValid) != username.end())
    return false;

return true;
```

---

Note that `isalpha` is in the `std::` namespace in C++. [Technically we should also cast to `unsigned char` when calling the function.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) (We could wrap that in a function of our own).

Comment: I would move the empty check to the beginning of the function. Returning early if the user passes in an empty string asserts that every other call will guarantee at least a non-empty string.

Comment: Since this is a code review site, I'd like to point out that many coding standards would forbid removing the `{` and `}` around the body of the if statement. It's far too easy to come along later and add a line in between the `if` and `return`, which will look at a glance like both lines are part of the same condition, but will actually make the return unconditional, completely breaking the function. Worst is when this happens because you're trying to debug something else, so you add a print or assert line in there.

Comment: I don't personally agree. Anecdotally, I've come across many coding standards that recommend using one-line `if` or `for` statements where possible (with perhaps some restrictions for if / else if / else, and empty following statements), and none that forbid it.

Comment: @user673679 Fair enough, I thought it was fairly widely accepted. For what it's worth, the top two results I found for "C++ coding style" on DuckDuckGo were [Mozilla's](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/code-quality/coding-style/coding_style_cpp.html#control-structures), which says "Always brace controlled statements"; and [Google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Conditionals), which allows limited use of un-braced if statements "for historical reasons", and notes that "Some projects require curly braces always."

Comment: I haven't done c++ in a really, really long time but by the time you are executing the second `if`, isn't `username.empty()` impossible because you've already checked that `username.length() < MIN_NAME_LENGTH`?

Comment: @JeffC Not if `MIN_NAME_LENGTH` is set to zero. (Which it almost certainly shouldn't be... but we want to avoid undefined behaviour even if it is.)

Comment: @user673679 hmpf. If you think it necessary, add a `static_assert()` or if needed `assert()` to check for lack of sanity.

Answer (score 21):

While in the general case of deconstructing [arrow-code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern), [conversion to guard-clauses](//refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html) as [demonstrated](/a/259354) by [user673679](/u/22697) is the way to go, in this case there is an alternative way to escape the damage caused by blind adherence to [single entry, single exit](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118793/155513);
Change it to a single return-expression:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string_view>

bool isValidUserName(std::string_view s) noexcept {
    return s.length() >= min_name_length
        && s.length() <= max_name_length
        && std::isalpha((unsigned char)s[0])
        && std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), isNotValid) == s.end();
}
```

Other points changed:

1. As by design, none of the tests can throw an exception, I amended the contract with `noexcept`.
2. As the argument is only inspected and never stored, and none of the code needs a nul-terminated string, accepting as `std::string` by value or constant reference are both sub-optimal. Receiving a `std::string_view` by value is more flexible and efficient.
   See [When should I use string_view in an interface?](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/364093) for more detail.
3. Generally prefer the C++-headers over the C legacy-headers. They put all their members in the `std` namespace like the other standard headers (though might also clutter the global namespace, instead of the other way around).
4. The character-classification-functions and case-conversion-functions expect an `unsigned char` value or `EOF` (`-1`) in an `int`. Because they also accept `EOF`, accepting an `unsigned char` or converting internally is unfortunately not on the cards for them. Avoid the trap of implementation-defined raw `char` signedness by adding a cast.
5. Changed `min_name_length` and `max_name_length` to lower case as upper case signals preprocessor defines, which they really shouldn't be. The preprocessor plays by its own rules.
6. Changed the only arguments name to `s`, because there is nothing for it convey not already in the function-name, and it is the only local in a nice short scope.

Answer (score 1):

One more tip not mentioned by the others:  Take your parameter as `std::string_view` instead of `const std::string&`.  This will be more efficient if called with a lexical string literal or other C-style string.

Instead of seeing if you can `find` something that's not legal in the string, with its awkward need to test against `end`, and throwing away the position where it was found anyway; instead use `std::all_of`, which clearly states the intent:  "do all the values pass the test?".  Well, if you insist on having `isNotValid` as the predicate for testing each letter, then use `none_of` instead.

The code is not shown, but the lack of braces makes me suspect that `isNotValid` is a simple function.  It actually generates better code to make such predicates functors (function objects) instead!  Though if you had defined it as a lambda expression it would still be a bare name as shown; I really don't know what you did there.

Comment: `std::string_view` is point 2 of changes made in my answer. Using `std::none_of()` is an idea though.